# Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Contract__r at line 9 column 18 in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

where Billing_Entity__c is picklist field on contract which is lookup on invoice.
kindely help me in this issue .Thanks in advance

```
trigger InvoiceAutoNumber on Invoice__c (before Insert) {
    List<AggregateResult> res = [SELECT Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c cb, MAX(Counter__c) max1 FROM Invoice__c where Counter__c !=null group by Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c];
    System.debug('---RG---' +res);
    Map<String, Invoice__c> rtMap = new Map<String,Invoice__c>();

    string Entity = '';
    List<Invoice__c> invList= [Select id, Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c from Invoice__c];
    for(Invoice inv:invList){
        Entity = inv.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c;
        rtMap.put(Entity , inv);
    }
    System.debug('---RG---' +rtMap);
    Map<String,Integer> counterMap= new Map<String,Integer>();

    for(AggregateResult ag :res ){
        counterMap.put(String.ValueOF(ag.get('cb')), Integer.valueOf(ag.get('max1')));
    }
    System.debug('---RG---' +counterMap);
// my trigger not show any debug after this line===
    for(Invoice__c theRT: trigger.new){
        if(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c != null){
            string subs= '';
            If(rtMap.containsKey(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c)){
                System.debug('---RG---' +rtMap.get(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c).Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c);
                if(rtMap.get(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c).Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c== 'RG UK')
                subs = 'UK';
                else if(rtMap.get(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c).Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c== 'RG India') 
                subs = 'IND';
                else
                subs = 'O';
            }else{
                subs = 'O';
            }
            System.debug('---subs ---' +subs);
            System.debug('---RG---' +counterMap.containsKey(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c));
            System.debug('---RG---' +counterMap.get(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c));
            Integer count= (counterMap.containsKey(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c)? counterMap.get(theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c)+1:0);
            theRT.counter__c = count;
            string strNum = string.valueOf(count);
            while(strNum.length() < 6){
                strNum= '0'+strNum;
            }
            theRT.Invoice_Auto_Number__c= subs + '-'+ strNum;
            System.debug('---Auto number---' +theRT.Invoice_Auto_Number__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the relation API name is `Contract__r` ? If not check it in your WSDL and retry

Comment: Contract is a standard field so that Contract__r is not the API name of it.

Comment: Invoice__c is a custom object so Contract__c is a valid name for a lookup to standard object Contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have added a custom field called Contract__c that is a lookup to a Contract on your Invoice__c then the Contract__r reference should be fine.

There is an error in the loop:

```
for(Invoice inv:invList){
```

that should be:

```
for(Invoice__c inv:invList){
```

that is a likely cause of the problem.

Comment: it gives no error for now but it's not working. debug log is not showing any action after'// my trigger not show any debug after this line===' .

Comment: @Abhinav That is the separate problem that Trigger.new only includes the immediate fields of the trigger object and not any related fields. So instead of `theRT.Contract__r.Billing_Entity__c` you will have to use `theRT.Contract__c` as the key in a map you have previously queried of Contract objects.